# mix-blend-mode: difference looks different in Chrome than in Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, filter, cross-browser, mix-blend-mode

So I have a custom cursor that uses [`mix-blend-mode: exclusion`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode) [in my website](https://gmzcodes.com/).

The cursor's original colour (without considering `mix-blend-mode`) is `cyan` and most elements below it are either `white`, `black`, `blue` or `magenta`, so the colours you can see there are these:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 25vh;
  width: 50vh;
  height: 50vh;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  background: #0FF;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="background: #FFF;"></div>
<div class="box" style="background: #00F;"></div>
<div class="box" style="background: #000;"></div>
<div class="box" style="background: #F0F;"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
```

However, that doesn't look the same in Chrome than it does in Firefox.

**Chrome (`Version 81.0.4044.113 (Official Build) (64-bit)`):**

[image]

**Firefox (`Version 75.0 (64-bit)`):**

[image]

I'd like to know if there's a way to make both looks the same.

I have been playing around with other values for `mix-blend-mode` (`exclusion`, in particular) and [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter), but I can't get anything to look consistent in both and maintain a similar behaviour.

Funny enough, if you change the colour of the cusror (`.circle` in the example), it works fine for most other values...

Comment: I show same in both browser

Comment: @NishargShah Which versions are you using?

Comment: Latest versions of both , same version you specified in your post

Comment: I am using also the same Chrome version that you say, and it renders the same than in Firefox ....  (that, by the way, is the correct one)

Comment: Ok, thank you both, then it probably has to do with some weird GPU or drivers issue on this computer, as I haven't been able to reproduce it anywhere and it also looks like that on the new Edge, so definitely not related to `about:flags` either. Will find out soon once I replace some components on this build  